# Encrypting cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I trying to encrypt and decrypt cookies using the following code. I able to encrypt but decrypting function accepts byte input. how can I can convert cookie to a byte for decrypting? The error is

> *cannot implicitly convert type "System.Web.HttpCookie" to "byte[]*

The error line is "byte[] encrypted = myCookie;" How can I convert the "cookie" to byte[] before decrypting?

`Enryption:`

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("co");
myCookie.Values.Add("customerId", dr["customerId"].ToString());

using (AesCryptoServiceProvider myAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] encrypted = AesEncryption.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(myCookie.ToString(),    myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
}
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Decription:

```
HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["co"];
byte[] encrypted = myCookie;

using (AesCryptoServiceProvider myAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
   string decripted = AesEncryption.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(myCookie.ToString(), myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
}
```

Comment: Your encrypted values does not get added to the cookie in the first place ?

Comment: shouldn't you use byte[] encrypted = myCookie.ToString..dont encrpt the cookie rather encrypt the information present in it.

Comment: MachineKey.Protect might be a better choice for encrypting data in ASP.NET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are trying to do, is to encrypt a value, then set that value in the cookie. The code shown does not do that. What you need to do is to:

1. Encrypt the value
2. Convert your encrypted bytes to a printable string (because cookies are plain text), base64 encoding is a common option for this.
3. Set that value in the cookie.
4. Set the cookie in the Response.

When trying to get back to the original value, run same process backwards.

Comment: I can convert the encrypted data to string but cannot add to cookie. how can I apply base64 encoding?

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(myCookie.ToString());
string str1 = Convert.ToBase64String(b1);

byte[] b2 = Convert.FromBase64String(str1);
string str2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("co");

using (AesCryptoServiceProvider myAes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    byte[] encrypted = AesEncryption.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(dr["customerId"].ToString(), myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
myCookie.Values.Add("customerId", Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
}
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

and do the reverse before decryption

```
HttpCookie myCookie = Request.Cookies["co"];
byte[] encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(myCookie.Value);
```